# How to solve "bad CPU type in executable" when compiled on M1?

Tags: xcode, runtime-error, apple-silicon

I'm using XCode 14.2 on a M1 and an Intel Mac. In "Build Settings" there is set in "Architecture" in both Debug and Release an entry of "Standard Architecture (Apple Silicon, Intel)". But when compiling on M1, I get error message on INTEL based mac when executed, while when compiled on INTEL it worked fine for both.
Is there another setting responsible to build a fat executable?

Comment: Build for current architecture only?

Comment: Maybe, but what can I set if I did already "Standard Architecture (Apple Silicon, Intel)". Where is "Current" or better "Both"?

Comment: I'm asking you what the Build Active Architecture Only setting is. If it's Yes, your Silicon-build app won't run on Intel. Current is Yes, Both is No.

Comment: You got it! Thanks a lot. It was on "Yes", now its on "No".

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer. There's always a chance someone else will find themselves in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the Build Active Architecture Only setting. If it's Yes, your Silicon-built app won't run on Intel. If it is, try switching it to No and see if that fixes the problem.

The usual thing is Yes for a debug build and No for a release build, because if you say No then the build has to be done twice, and one usually doesn't want to do that for mere debugging purposes.